# How to relearn English grammar

Tags: english, grammar

I am learning Arabic grammar as a hobby, and so far I’ve learned how to form simple sentences and phrases, as well as the types of nouns, verbs, and particles.

While learning Arabic grammar from scratch, I’ve noticed that my English grammar is lacking, and I would like to go through the same process of building myself up again with English. I believe this would help me understand both languages better.

I would like to relearn the types of words, phrases, sentences and how to form them correctly, and be able to grammatically analyze sentences from books or articles. As kids we learned by imitating but I would like to learn formally as I am in My Arabic class.

What are your recommendations for books or references regarding English grammar and usage? Preferably I would like a book to skim through. My background: I am an engineering college graduate.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning SE. Even though you are looking specifically for recommendations related to grammar, it would be helpful if you could (1) give a rough estimate of your current level and (2) say what you would primarily use English for (reading, writing, conversation, ..?).